# What is the syntax to use part of the version from CSPROJ and AppVeyor {build} to get a 2.0.x style build number?

Tags: c#, .net, build, appveyor

Is it possible to have AppVeyor builds use the build number from the csproj file but replace the 'patch' version with the `{build}` variable?

For Example:

```
CSPROJ: <Version>2.1.0</Version>
AppVeyor: ??? What goes here? Manually setting 2.1.{build} will work but then to rev to 2.2, we have to update appveyor AND csproj.
Output: 2.1.15 (assuming build number is 15)
```

Is this possible with the build-in AppVeyor Patching system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Just replace subfolder and file name in `$xmlPath`

```
install:
- ps: |
    $xmlPath = "$env:appveyor_build_folder\mysubfolder\myproject.csproj"
    $xml = [xml](get-content $xmlPath)
    $version = ($xml.Project.PropertyGroup | ? {$_.Version}).Version
    $env:newversion = ($version.Substring(0, $version.LastIndexOf(".") + 1)) + $env:appveyor_build_number

dotnet_csproj:
  patch: true
  file: '**\*.csproj'
  version: $(newversion)
  package_version: $(newversion)
  assembly_version: $(newversion)
  file_version: $(newversion)
  informational_version: $(newversion)
```